# Symbolic function for a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, symbolic-math

I want to define a symbolic vector in Matlab, but every element of the vector should be created through a symbolic function.

Let's say f(x)=x^2 is my function and I have a vector A=[1 2 3 4 5]. I want to create a symbolic vector so that it is going to be like this;

Symbolic_vector=[x^2 2*x^2 3*x^2 4*x^2 5*x^2]

How can I realize this ?

So far I have

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5];
syms x;   
m = sym('m', [1 100]);                                             
f = sym('x^2*m');
f = subs(f, m, A);
```

Comment: The result is not going to be symbolc, but numeric with `[1^2,2^2,3^3,...]`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this and keep things symbolic is

```
A = sym('[1 2 3 a 5]');
f = @(x) x.^2;
B = f(A);

% results in B = [1 4 9 a^2 25]
```

You can also do directly

```
B = A.^2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
syms a;

A = [1 2 3 a 5];

B = A.^2;
```

I hope this helps.